# SSLPeerUnverifiedException when using JSOUP

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, jsoup

I'm trying to use JSOUP to parse a webpage in a LAN so I dont think I need a valid SSL certificate since it will be in a trusted network. I've created a Class that extends AsyncTask in order to override the doInBackground(...) method like this:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            //Connect to the website
            String url = "https://my.example.webpage/";

            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();


            String title = document.title();
            Log.d("TAG","WEB TITLE" + title);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that I'm getting SSLPeerUnverifiedException when trying to execute the specific line:

> Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).get();

My system output says:

```
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname my.example.webpage not verified:
    certificate: sha1/wJ/Px5KkDt2+bFjaXqgA9QE/Utk=
    DN: CN=xxx.xxx.xxx.cu
    subjectAltNames: [xxx.xxx.xxx.cu]
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:201)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
etc, etc, etc, etc
```

I'm using already ignoreHttpErrors(true) but still getting the error. I tried a url with a valid ssl certificate and everything work just fine.

What I'm trying is to parse some text from that page, and I'm open to any other solution if JSOUP can't solve the problem.

I tried to use a http page instead, but I get IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to my.example.webpage not permitted, so I'm freeze until I get a valid SSL certificate and I don't really want to use one, it should be possible to do it without security despite not being a good practice

Comment: Try with `.validateTLSCertificates(false)`.

Comment: This method seems to be deprecated in the newest version of Jsoup, maybe I need to use an older version

Comment: I downgraded JSOUP to 1.11.3 in order to be able to use .validateTLSCertificates(false) and it solved the problem, it's not probably the perfect solution, but it still a good solution